# Pretty displaying code in beamer

Tags: beamer, listings, verbatim, code

I am currently making my first beamer presentation, so forgive if this is a very trivial question. I have tried to research how to display code on a beamer presentation. I have managed to do this using `semiverbatim`. However, I am not completely satisfied with this as the readability is so poor without any coloring of keywords, etc. I have tried to use the `listings` package, with which I am familiar from writing articles in LaTeX, but I have not been successfull.

Here is an example from my presentation:

```
\begin{frame}[fragile]
\begin{semiverbatim}
class DampenedPendulum(Pendulum):
    def __init__(self, B, L=1, M=1, g=9.81):
        super().__init__(L=1, M=1, g=9.81)
        self.solve_called = False
        self.B = B
\end{semiverbatim}
\end{frame}
```

This comes out okay, but I would like to improve the readability by adding some coloring of keywords, like in the `listings` package. Any tips on how to that would be much appreciated.

Here is an example of how I tried to this using the `listings` package:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Boadilla}

\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor}
 
\definecolor{codegreen}{rgb}{0,0.6,0}
\definecolor{codegray}{rgb}{0.5,0.5,0.5}
\definecolor{codepurple}{rgb}{0.58,0,0.82}
\definecolor{backcolour}{rgb}{0.95,0.95,0.92}
 
\lstdefinestyle{mystyle}{
    backgroundcolor=\color{backcolour},   
    commentstyle=\color{codegreen},
    keywordstyle=\color{magenta},
    numberstyle=\tiny\color{codegray},
    stringstyle=\color{codepurple},
    basicstyle=\ttfamily\footnotesize,
    breakatwhitespace=false,         
    breaklines=true,                 
    captionpos=b,                    
    keepspaces=true,                 
    numbers=left,                    
    numbersep=5pt,                  
    showspaces=false,                
    showstringspaces=false,
    showtabs=false,                  
    tabsize=2
}

 
\lstset{style=mystyle}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[fragile]
\begin{lstlisting}
class DampenedPendulum(Pendulum):
    def __init__(self, B, L=1, M=1, g=9.81):
        super().__init__(L=1, M=1, g=9.81)
        self.solve_called = False
        self.B = B
\end{lstlisting}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

This comes out with numbered lines and background color, but not coloring of keywords. The code for styling was copied from an Overleaf page, and I have used it many times in articles for pretty printing code.

Comment: [Welcome to TEX.SE!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436/82917) You say you have tried to use the `listings` package so please show us what you have tried so far by giving us a [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/82917) starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Thanks for the respons! I have now done so, hopefully to a satisfactory extent.

Comment: You need to specify that the language is Python (`language=Python` in your `\lstdefinestyle`). Also your MWE is helpful but it is missing `\begin{document}` and `\end{document}`.

Comment: That worked - simple as that! Thank you so much! I have also added the `\begin{document}` and `\end{document}` for future reference of this question.

Comment: @Marijn Would you like to write an answer?

Answer (score 1):

For `listings` to know the keywords, string syntax, number format, comment syntax etc, you need to provide a language identifier. In this case you should add `language=Python` to `\lstdefinestyle{mystyle}`.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Boadilla}

\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor}
 
\definecolor{codegreen}{rgb}{0,0.6,0}
\definecolor{codegray}{rgb}{0.5,0.5,0.5}
\definecolor{codepurple}{rgb}{0.58,0,0.82}
\definecolor{backcolour}{rgb}{0.95,0.95,0.92}
 
\lstdefinestyle{mystyle}{
    language=Python,
    backgroundcolor=\color{backcolour},   
    commentstyle=\color{codegreen},
    keywordstyle=\color{magenta},
    numberstyle=\tiny\color{codegray},
    stringstyle=\color{codepurple},
    basicstyle=\ttfamily\footnotesize,
    breakatwhitespace=false,         
    breaklines=true,                 
    captionpos=b,                    
    keepspaces=true,                 
    numbers=left,                    
    numbersep=5pt,                  
    showspaces=false,                
    showstringspaces=false,
    showtabs=false,                  
    tabsize=2
}

 
\lstset{style=mystyle}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[fragile]
\begin{lstlisting}
class DampenedPendulum(Pendulum):
    def __init__(self, B, L=1, M=1, g=9.81):
        super().__init__(L=1, M=1, g=9.81)
        self.solve_called = False
        self.B = B
        print(23, "is a number")
        # print statements should not be in the constructor
\end{lstlisting}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]